# Making files public when doing an rsync with gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When doing the usual `gsutil -m rsync -r . gs://bucket/` I would like the files to be public by default instead of having to do a `gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://bucket` afterwards.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a default object ACL on the bucket:

```
gsutil defacl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://your-bucket
```

Answer (score 9):

gsutil now have a `-a` flag to set a canned ACL on copied files:

`gsutil -m rsync -a public-read -r . gs://bucket/`